# Parsing logical order of execution from string

Tags: php

I'm building a system which queries PDM system.

What's the best way to parse string with logical operators. Let's say that the input string is in form:

```
$string = '( (a OR b) and (a AND c) )';
```

Now, given that a, b and c will be replaced with appropriate query clauses (which are inputted separately), whats the best way to parse this? The query is not limited to a, b and c (there may be more or less clauses) and the nesting level is not limited to 2.

The end result should be like:

```
$query->createContainer("and")
    ->createContainer("or")
        ->addCondition("a")
        ->addCondition("b")
        ->getParent()  //this moves the internal pointer back to parent container
    ->createContainer("and")
         ->addCondition("a")
         ->addCondition("c");
```

I've already built the object interface for queries (shown above), but I'm having trouble parsing the input string. I can still affect the form of the input string so also improvement suggestions there are appreciated.

Example of more complex string:
    $string = '( (a OR(c AND a)) or (a AND (f OR (d AND g))) )';

Thank you for your help!

Comment: GOOGLE "shunting yard algorithm" for converting infix to postfix notation, then that will give you a logical order of execution

Comment: Thanks for reply! I checked the wikipedia article. Could you give me a hint how to implement the algorithm in this case?